# Loading an HDF dataset into python, but it's recognized as empty

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, hdf

I am trying to load a large 400x300x60x28 dataset from Matlab (.mat file) into Python as an HDF file, but every time I try to see what's in the file it says it is empty.

Some things I've tried so far:

**INPUT:**

```
    f=h5py.File(r'D:\Natalie\Research\Vascular Hand\output.mat','r')
    print(f)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    <HDF5 file "output.mat" (mode r+)>
```

**INPUT:**

```
    store=pd.HDFStore(r'D:\Natalie\Research\Vascular Hand\output.mat')
    print(store)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
    File path: D:\Natalie\Research\Vascular Hand\output.mat
    Empty
```

**INPUT:**

```
    f = pd.read_hdf(r'D:\Natalie\Research\Vascular Hand\output.mat')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    ValueError: No dataset in HDF5 file.
```

It's saying there is no dataset, but I just opened the same file in Matlab and it has over 500,000 elements. Just to give some context, it is a variable of type 4-D single in Matlab and it is time-of-arrival data from blood circulation tracked through MRI scans.

Comment: Is the mat file saved as version 7.3? Does it work if you save it with [`h5write`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5write.html)?

Comment: Yes, it is version 7.3. I tried h5write like you said to save it as a .h5 file, but it still recognizes the dataset as empty when I try to read it into Python.

Answer (score 0):

To read `.mat` files one might use [`scipy.io.loadmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)

```
data = scipy.io.loadmat("example.mat")
```